# Stop printing content with PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve content from another domain by using PHP and store it inside a variable using jQuery. But I've no idea why it keeps printing out the content.

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
?>

<script>
  var content = '<?php echo $content; ?>';
</script>


EDITED: 
----------
<script>
  var content = escape('<?php echo addslashes($content); ?>');
</script>
```

It's still not working with this edited version.

Comment: you have to put it in quotes and escape any quotes so it won't break your javascript code.

Comment: Do you mean var content = '<?php echo $content; ?>';

Comment: yes, also the content that would come from google.com would have tons of single and double quotes and other special characters. you should escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're planning on doing with the content once it is collected, but this will allow you to store it without having it print. It may be useful if you plan on getting the contents of an API or similar.

```
<body id="place-content">
</body>

<?php
  $content = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var content = <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>;
   // Uncomment this line to have 'content' print...
   //document.getElementById("place-content").innerHTML = content; 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan! This is what I'm looking for! Now I can setup a proxy to retrieve certain element in external websites.Could you tell me what is the format that PHP retrieves? and so we need to use json_encode?

Answer (score 1):

try to put ascape like bellow and addslashes to php

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
?>

<script>
  var content = escape('<?php echo addslashes($content); ?>');
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: It's still printing out the content even added escape and addslashes